# Rounded corners for an iframe not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, iframe, safari

So, I know that `border-radius` doesn't really work on an `iframe` itself, but what you can do to get a similar effect is to wrap that `iframe` in a `div`, and set the `border-radius` on the div itself, like so:

```
<div class="modal-iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe class="modal-iframe"></iframe>
</div>

.modal-iframe-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

This, however, doesn't seem to work in Safari, and I couldn't find any other recent workarounds (the few questions/answers about this on SO are pretty outdated by now). Is there a clean solution to this for Safari?

Comment: Okay apparently this does actually work, but having something `position: fixed` in the iframe content is what breaks the rounded corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly doesn't work? I have tested it in Safari but it seems to be working.

```
<div class="modal-iframe-wrapper">
 <iframe class="modal-iframe" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
</div>

.modal-iframe-wrapper {
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 8px;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background: red;
}
iframe { widith: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jwb546k6/

Comment: Oh, so it does. I dug into my own situation more, and it seems like if you have something inside the iframe that's `position: fixed`, then the rounded corners no longer work. You can see this by setting the h1 inside the example page to fixed and watch the corners disappear.

Answer (score 15):

I know this question is old but I ran into this today and none of the above solutions worked. This is what ended up working for me. I had to add the webkit mask image to the iframe wrapper.

```
    .iframe-wrapper{
       //other css here
       border-radius: 10px;           
       -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
    }

   <div class="iframe-wrapper">
      <iframe></iframe>
   </div>
```

Comment: You saved my day.

Comment: This fixed an issue where the rounded cropping worked on desktop Chrome and Safari but not on either mobile version.

Comment: This is the answer for mobile... saved me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `overflow: hidden` to the "wrapper" and

```
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
```

To the `modal-iframe`. Then you can change the height using the "wrapper".

```css
.modal-iframe-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.modal-iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe class="modal-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `border-radius` to the `iframe` instead

```css
.modal-iframe {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe class="modal-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`clip-path` CSS property also worked for me.

```
clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0% round 10px);
```